# Is there a way to get a revision count of a post?

Tags: revisions

Is there a way to get the revision count number of a post? I've seen how to get the revisions but I don't want to get the revisions just the count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`wp_get_post_revisions ( int|WP_Post $post_id,  $args = null )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_revisions/). It returns an array of revisions for the passed post ID or an empty array if a passed post does not have any revisions.

Note that the `$args` parameter accepts all parameters valid for `WP_Query`

```
$q = wp_get_post_revisions( 513 );
echo count( $q );
?><pre><?php var_dump($q); ?></pre><?php
```

### EDIT

From your comments about custom fields, custom fields does not trigger the post revision system.

I'm not going to discuss how the revision system works, but in short, when a post is updated, the old and new values of the **`WP_Post`** is compared. There are a specific action for that, [`post_updated`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/). If these value don't match, a revision is created (*if revisions are enabled*).

Now, custom fields are not part of the `WP_Post` object, there for, whenever you just update a custom field, a post revision will not be created as the post object remains the same. Also, custom fields also don't have a revision system, so old values are completely overwritten by new values

Comment: Strange. I'm not showing any revisions. Are revisions only created when the document is published?

Comment: Interesting... It won't save revisions OR show the revisions panel UNLESS the document body changes. That seems like a good idea but I've been updating the custom metadata and pulling my hair out trying to figure out why no revisions were being saved!!!

Comment: Revisions (if enabled) are created when a post is updated. Note that, by default, custom post types don't have revisions enabled.

Comment: To be honest, the revision system is a really crappy one which I really dont like

Comment: lol. thanks. i'll keep my expectations low. btw I should clarify I meant custom fields. Go into a post, display the custom fields screen and enter and save some data. You have to press the update button by the custom field not the Save Draft button. After the page reloads you'll see there is no revisions or no new revisions.

Comment: Please see my update. In short, custom field updates does not trigger revisions

Comment: Welp, there goes my project. :( It's been overwritten. One hour down the drain and now I'm not sure I can use WP the way I had hoped. I originally was trying to use the post content body but WP filters and changes it so my data was lost or modified so I started using the custom fields.